# inject last part of URL dynamically and uniquely using javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, csv

I am trying to work out how to get thye last part of a url on click of a button dynamically from a pre populated csv file.

For example on click of `<a href="mysite.com/" >button</a>`
would grab a code from a CSV file (or something better) and the link would be `mysite.com/code1.`

However each code from the CSV will only be used once and be removed after

So first click = `mysite.com/code1`

Second click = `mysite.com/code2`

and so on getting `code1` and `code2` from the CSV file and never to be gotten again.

I can use either JavaScript or PHP, either is good, I'm just not sure on the syntax.

Comment: `window.location.href="mysite.com/"+$codeVariable`, this would change the url w. javascript. You can read the csv with php and store as much codes as you need in an array for javascript to use

Comment: Does this "code" you're grabbing have some sort of meaning? Is it related to something?

Comment: its just a code that has a one time use voucher linked to it

Comment: Hmm, my code will cycle through the same csv links for each user unless you change the csv for each user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
<?php
 $first = true;
 $links = "";
 $file = fopen('myCSVFile.csv', 'r');
 while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
   if (!$first) $links.=",";
   $first=false;
   //$line is an array of the csv elements
   $links.='"'.$line.'"';
 }
 fclose($file);
?>
```

Plain JS

```
<script>
var links = [<?php echo $links ?>];
cnt = 0;
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("csvLink").onclick=function() {
    window.open(this.href+links[cnt],"_blank"); // otherwise you need cookies
    return false;
    cnt++; 
  }
}
</script>
```

jQuery using Ajax:

```
<script>
var links = [<?php echo $links ?>];
cnt = 0;
$(function() {
  $("#csvLink").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#someContainer").load(this.href+links[cnt]);
    cnt++; 
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I was just reading through the answer to understand the code fully before i accepted it

Comment: No problem. Good luck